Is there a software that pronounces the words and names?
Is there a computer program where you can input a word or a name and a language as text, and it pronounces the word/name in the specified language as audio?

There's a very commonly used one - Google Translate.
You click the Listen button and that's it:



YouGlish is a website that lets you search for words, phrases and topics in different languages and get fast, unbiased answers about how they are spoken by real people and in context.


YouGlish supports  Arabic, Chinese, Dutch, English, French, German, Greek, Hebrew, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Swedish, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian, Vietnamese, and Sign Languages.

The results returned through the website and the app consist of a video, the audio of the target word, and the transcript. You might be able to get only the audio through the API. It doesn't necessarily have every possible word or name. I've used it to find names pronounced by native speakers.
https://youglish.com/
